# Update MySQL database using php statement

Tags: php, mysql, modx

I am trying to update a value in a MySQL database with the following function which creates an update statement that subtracts the value of the **$seats** variable from the existing value in the **places** field in the database.
The code below returns 0 instead of reducing the places value by the value of the $seats variable.

```
    $update_seats = update_places($id);

    function update_places($id) {
         global $modx;
         $table = "`database_name`.`table_name`";
         $update_seats = '`places`' - $seats;
         $result = $modx->db->update( '`places` = ' . $update_seats, $table, '`id` = "' . $id . '" AND `places` > 0' );
         return $result;         // Returns 'true' on success, 'false' on failure.
```

}

Any help with correcting my syntax is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to change `$update_seats = '\`places\`' - $seats;` by : `$update_seats = '\`places\` - ' . $seats;`

Comment: What is your $modx variable?  It also looks like you haven't defined $seats.

Comment: Hi Seb33300 - thank you for your help.
I have tried your suggestion with the following error result message:
`SQL > UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `places` = `places` - ($seats value should be here) WHERE `id` = "1104" AND `places` > 0`
The value of the $seats variable is not being sent.
It is declared further up the page outside the funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$seats` variable is undefined inside function, you need to use:

`function update_places($id, $seats)`

and then call it `$update_seats = update_places($id, 123);`

also, change your query to be more correct:

```
$result = $modx->db->update( '`places` = ' . $update_seats, $table, '`id` = ' . intval($id, 10) . ' AND `places` >= ' . $seats );
```